# AppsFlyer SDK iOS integration error Code=3840 "No value."

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I've integrated the AppsFlyer SDK but continuously getting the following error:

It calls the following delegate func

```
-(void)onConversionDataFail:(NSError *) error {
  NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

And the console output is the following:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}
```

I'm using the latest pod, and have configured the app accordingly to AppsFlyer tutorial:

```
[AppsFlyerLib shared].appsFlyerDevKey = @"<AF_DEV_KEY>";
[AppsFlyerLib shared].appleAppID = @"<APPLE_APP_ID>";
[AppsFlyerLib shared].delegate = self;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(sendLaunch:)
     name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
     object:nil];

- (void)sendLaunch:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[AppsFlyerLib shared] start];
}
```

<AF_DEV_KEY> and <APPLE_APP_ID> replaced with my app id in real code

Could you please suggest how to fix the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Help yourself by running a simple search for the exact error message you have written above.

Comment: Hi @ElTomato, thank you for your response. I've searched before creating the question, unfortunately didn't find anything related to AppsFlyer & 3840 error. I've also reached out to AppsFlyer support but there are no response yet. Let me know if you have something to share with the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved the problem. It was related to AppsFlyer "Zero" plan that doesn't support mobile attribution.
After switching to paid plan the problem got resolved.

It was also returning "403" error